# Не работает метод .show() в Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

Заметил что у меня не работает метод `show()`, работает только `exec()`, но он блокирует дальнейшее выполнение программы до закрытия окна.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "progress.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::encode_file() 
{
    Progress progress;
    progress.setModal(true);
    progress.show(); //Окно progress по непонятной причине не отображается. Если же меняю на exec(), то всё работает.

}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Добавил часть кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас окно `Progress` существует только внутри метода `MainWindow::encode_file()`

Вам надо создавать прогресс на динамике, например так

В классе объявить `Progress* prg;`

В конструкторе класса `prg=new Progress(this);`

В теле метода - `prg->show();`

Comment: Модраторы уже похоже сами откатили. Сейчас старую версию вопроса вижу